# Overlapping button cells in WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to achieve a quadratic grid of buttons such as none of the grid cells overlap.

It's also important that the buttons shall be positioned at the centre of each cell with visible gaps separating them from each other.

```
<Grid  Margin="0,0,0,-6" 
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.505,0.323" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
      Width="810" Height="610" 
      VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
```

Here's a code snippet I have been experiencing with (MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
{
    RowDefinition r = new RowDefin
    r.Height = new GridLength(1000, GridUnitType.Star);
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(r);
                
    for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++)
    {
                    ColumnDefinition c = new ColumnDefinition();
                    c.Width = new GridLength(20, GridUnitType.Star);
                    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c);

                    Button b = new Button();
                    b.Width = 20;
                    b.Height = 20;
                    
                    b.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                    Grid.SetRow(b, i);
                    Grid.SetColumn(b, j);
                    grid.Children.Add(b);

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this produces a seemingly overlapping configuration. So my question is how should I fix the issue of overlapping and construct spaces between individual buttons.

Comment: Is there are reason you are not doing this in XAML?

Comment: You should not use the absolute values, use the relative values for width and height

Comment: I'd like to achieve the button grid setup dynamically in the context of MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is become more familiar with the WPF standard controls. I believe what you seek is some combination of a `UniformGrid` and `TextBlock`.

```
<UniformGrid  Height="100" Width="120">
    <UniformGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Name="BorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Brown"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Name="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Wheat"/>

        </Style>                
    </UniformGrid.Resources>
    <Border>
        <TextBlock Text="Pizza"/></Border>
    <Border>
        <TextBlock Text="Pizza"/>
    </Border>
    <Border >
        <TextBlock Text="Pizza"/>
    </Border>
    <Border>
        <TextBlock Text="Pizza"/>
    </Border>
</UniformGrid>
```

This gives you a basic grid pattern, its up to you to make it to what you need:

[image]

The MVVM  of a project to just store data. That data can then be inserted into the the controls to dynamically create items.